# Roslyn Project Templates VS 2015 RC

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn

I can't find any Project Templates for Roslyn Extensions in the current released Visual Studio 2015 RC. Are they not available in the Release Candidate or just well hidden?

I am missing the whole Roslyn folder.
I have installed the Visual Studio 2015 SDK RC, do I still miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have moved to the Extensibility folder, and don't have Roslyn in the name. Instead they are named after what they actually do.

Additionally, they aren't part of the base Visual Studio install.  You need to install the VS SDK, and the Roslyn templates VSIX at https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e2e07e91-9d0b-4944-ba40-e86bcbec1599.

Comment: The Extensibility Folder only shows "VSIX" Project, nothing like Roslyn syntax analyser or similar. What should i look for?

Comment: Actually, they are a separate VSIX that you need to install: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e2e07e91-9d0b-4944-ba40-e86bcbec1599