# Where to find Roslyn Project Templates for VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30004699/roslyn-project-templates-vs-2015-rc) but the accepted answer provide two no working links. If you click on them you will see something like:

> This item is not yet published. If you are the owner of this project,
>   please sign in with the appropriate account.

So my question is. Where to find the installers for Roslyn Project Templates for VS 2015?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the .Net Compiler Platform SDK: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2ddb7240-5249-4c8c-969e-5d05823bcb89

You may also need to install the Visual Studio 2015 SDK: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441(v=vs.140).aspx

You can also download the .Net Compiler Platform SDK from within Visual Studio:

[image]

Comment: just installed and still without finding the roslyn project templates for c# under file->new project

Comment: Try File > New Project > C# > Extensibility

Comment: Confusingly, the templates don't show up under just `Visual C#` like some other templates do - you have to go to `Extensibility` within `Visual C#`

Comment: Be aware that you need to have selected at least .NET 4.5.2 before these templates are available. I was unable to see them, but it was because I had .NET 4.5 selected

Comment: it wasnt working for me as well. I had to uninstall the templates, close all of my visual studios, restart, open a new "Download the .Net Compiler...." download the templates, restart VS, then BAMM, it worked...  it looks like the image above (as of VS14.0.25431.01 Update 3)

Comment: I had to select .NET 4.6, selecting .Net 4.5.2 does not work any more.