# Roslyn templates do not show up on VS2015 professional

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn

I couldn't find Roslyn templates in Visual Studio 2015 Professional(Update 3) after performing the following steps. Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated.

1) Strictly followed instruction provided at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-on-Visual-Studio-2015

2) Refered to the following stack overflow question, made sure >Net Framework 4.5.2 is selected, still no success
[Where to find Roslyn Project Templates for VS 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776083/where-to-find-roslyn-project-templates-for-vs-2015)

3) Below is a screenshot of "New Project" window when ".Net Framework 4.6" is selected.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the drop down at the top of the New Project Dialog is targeting .NET 4.6 or higher.

Comment: Thank you, could you please suggest if Roslyn templates appear under "Visual C#" or under "Visual C# -> Extensibility".

Comment: I have added screenshot of "New Project" window when ".Net Framework 4.6" is selected to my question.